# Using environment variable for volumes in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to bind environment variables and values that I set in docker compose, however I don't understand how to reference them, I'm trying like this but it doesn't work

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    environment:
      LOG_PATH_HOST: C:/Users/Anton/Data
      LOG_PATH_CONTAINER: /var/log/kotlin_logger/
    volumes:
      - LOG_PATH_HOST:LOG_PATH_CONTAINER
```

Comment: `${VAR}`, though I don't know whether it works for volumes; see https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: I have tried this, however in this case it looks for environment variables on my host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put environment variables for docker-compose into a file called `.env` in the same directory as the docker-compose file.

Example:

.env file

```
DOCKER_COMPOSE_VARIABLE=MyValue
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  myservice:
    image: my_image
    environment:
      CONTAINER_VARIABLE: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VARIABLE}
```

Now, when the container runs, it'll have an environment variable called CONTAINER_VARIABLE with the value 'MyValue'.

Comment: thank you so much, this is the answer, however how can I now change the environment variables directly in the container from the terminal? I want to send my docker image to a friend, but I don't understand how to make them able to change environment variables

Comment: When you say 'container', to me, that means a running instance of an image. So after it's started, you want to change an environment variable?

Comment: I meant just an image not running

Comment: Your friend can change any environment variables by adding the `-e` option on the `docker run` command. For example `docker run -e LOG_PATH_CONTAINER=/var/my/log/path image_name`. They can also set it in a docker-compose file if they use that to run the image.